# Nuxtjs/Vuejs set the default date time as current date time for the input field of type datetime-local

Tags: html, vue.js, input, nuxt.js, datetime-local

I have a Nuxtjs/Vuejs application that contains the input field of type `datetime-local`. For this field, I would like to add the current DateTime as the default value. I have done similar things in `AngularJS` but for some reason, it is not working in Vuejs.

Following is the field:

```html
<input v-model="formData.eventtimeSpecific" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" title="Set Specific Event Time">
```

Following is the JS function for it:

```js
export default {
 data(){
  return {
   formData:{
    eventtimeSpecific: new Date(),
   }
  }
 },
  mounted () {
    const today = new Date()
    this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.setHours(today.getHours(), today.getMinutes(), 0, 0)
  },
}
```

Similar approach when I tried in Angularjs it was working:

```js
$scope.formdata.eventtimeSpecific = new Date();
var h = $scope.formdata.eventtimeSpecific.getHours();
var m = $scope.formdata.eventtimeSpecific.getMinutes();
$scope.formdata.eventtimeSpecific.setHours(h,m,0,0);
```

Can someone please assist me in how to set the current DateTime value as the default value for `datetime-local` type input field?

Current behavior:

[image]

Expected behavior:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by deafault value? You mean input place holder?

Comment: no no, I want to make sure that when I open the web page the field should be filled with the current date and time. As of now it is empty.

Comment: @RobinGrundel I have modified the question a bit with expected and current behavior. Can you please have a look and suggest something?

Comment: Tried to answer, if you have any questions just ask me, if it answered the question, could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the
`this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.setHours(today.getHours(), today.getMinutes(), 0, 0)` returns time in this format `Wed Aug 25 2021 13:35:49 GMT+0200` but, `type="datetime-local"` accepts only this format `2021-08-25T13:36`

So you have to format it:

```
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = now.getDate();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var localDatetime =
      year +
      '-' +
      (month < 10 ? '0' + month.toString() : month) +
      '-' +
      (day < 10 ? '0' + day.toString() : day) +
      'T' +
      (hour < 10 ? '0' + hour.toString() : hour) +
      ':' +
      (minute < 10 ? '0' + minute.toString() : minute);
    this.formData.eventtimeSpecific = localDatetime;
```

Hope It helped!

**EDIT!**

Here is easier way to do it

```
this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.setMinutes(
      this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.getMinutes() - this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.getTimezoneOffset()
);
this.formData.eventtimeSpecific = this.formData.eventtimeSpecific.toISOString().slice(0, -8);
```

The slice -8 is there for not including the seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is working as expected. Just wanted to confirm if there is any way to shorten it a bit? Because Angular worked with few lines of code so was wondering if there is something similar here as well. Apart from that it's working fine.

Comment: Actaully there is, give me some time i will edit the answer

Comment: The first snippet of code is really ugly and I'd be totally opposed to suggest it to anybody. Rather use a `date-fns` library or alike. The second one looks better, just hope that it handles all the possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for the modification. Seems like its working as of now :)

Comment: I hope it supports all cases, but you should better testing before some production